# Collect specific items from dictionary values and create a new dictionary

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary object which is from the json response, I am trying to create a new dictionary with specific key:value pairs from that dictionary. Because it all is in a class, and functions expressed 
as methods.

Basic code flow:

Function1: take the d and check whether the d.keys() is 'result'

Function2: if F1 is true:

```
clean_result = x
for x in self.cleanResult(d['result']):
   clean_result = x

return clean_result
```

Function3:

```
def cleanResult(self, d):
     for x in d:
        yield {x['subject'],x['relationship'],x['object'],x['certainty']}
```

I cannot get my head around how to create such method and return a plural dictionary. When I print `cleanResult()` generator, it prints both dictionaries, but when `return clean_result` it only returns single result. Thanks.

I have been creating different type of methods to wrangle the dictionary data, extract data and create multiple dictionaries and return that value, but can't get it done.

The dictionary of the json file

```
d = {
    "result": [
        {
            "objectMetadata": {
                "en": [
                    {
                        "data": "A Romance Language, belonging to the Indo-European family that is an official Language in 29 countries, most of which form la francophonie (in French), the community of French-speaking countries.",
                        "dataType": "md"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "object": "French",
            "subject": "s",
            "factID": "WA:RF: 5877200994d54b1bc00004d29a1838f2dd31d9c1bc561da3d5a7871ad1b4c352",
            "relationship": "speaks",
            "relationshipType": "speaks",
            "certainty": 100
        },
        {
            "objectMetadata": {
                "en": [
                    {
                        "data": "German is a West Germanic Language that is mainly spoken in Central Europe",
                        "dataType": "md"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "object": "German",
            "subject": "s",
            "factID": "WA:RF: 73493afc878bc9c09917dd1108950007259b04f5a2c36bf8066fe54fa111610b",
            "relationship": "speaks",
            "relationshipType": "speaks",
            "certainty": 85
        }
    ],
    "stats": {
        "getDBFact": {
            "calls": 16,
            "items": 8,
            "ms": 28
        },
        "callDatasource": {
            "calls": 0,
            "ms": 0
        },
        "ensureCache": {
            "ms": 5
        },
        "setDBFact": {
            "calls": 4,
            "ms": 34
        },
        "updateDBFact": {
            "calls": 0,
            "ms": 0
        },
        "totalMS": 117,
        "approxEngineMS": 6,
        "totalConditionCount": 8,
        "invocationStartTime": 1560093937522
    },
    "createdAt": 1560093937582,
    "sid": "853986e0-4e9e-4655-b63e-7491d4a62464"
}
```

expected results that I want to receive is a list of dictionaries in the following format:

```
clean_result = 
{'1':{'subject':'s','relationship':'speaks':'object':'French','certainty':'100'},
'2':{'subject':'s','relationship':'speaks':'object':'Germany','certainty':'75'}}
```

Comment: `clean_result` doesn't look like list, do you want it to be dictionary of dictionaries or list of dictionaries?

Comment: @arjithn either way. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function found here you are overwriting the value of `clean_result` with each iteration. This is a very simple fix as you can change your code:

```py
clean_result = x
for x in self.cleanResult(d['result']):
   clean_result = x

return clean_result
```

to

```py
if d.get('result'):  # returns True if found else None
   clean_result = {}
   for i, x in enumerate(self.cleanResult(d['result'])):  # loop returns index (i) and value (x)
      clean_result[str(i)] = x

   return clean_result
```

This however still only returns a set of data instead of a dictionary like your expected data.

To return a dictionary use the code bleow:

```py
def cleanResult(self, d):
  for x in d:
    yield {"subject": x["subject"], "relationship": x["relationship"], "object": x["object"], "certainty": x["certainty"]}
```

this returns:

```
{'0': {'subject': 's', 'relationship': 'speaks', 'object': 'French', 'certainty': 100},
 '1': {'subject': 's', 'relationship': 'speaks', 'object': 'German', 'certainty': 85}}
```